# How do I locate a specific parent/child using Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell

I'm able to recursively search a directory using Get-ChildItem -Recurse to locate a particular directory, but I'm only interested in the case where the directory is a child of another specific directory.  The parent/child may exist at any arbitrary depth in the directory tree.  For instance:

C:\lev1\lev2\lev3\lev4\parentDir\childDirToFind\lev7...

The following code returns all occurrences of childDirToFind :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\\*\\*\ChildDirToFind -Recurse
```

I've tried including the parentDir in the -Path option and get no results; e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\\*\\*\parentDir\childDirToFind -Recurse
```

I've also tried to use the -Filter option with no results.  Perhaps Get-ChildItem isn't the best approach?  Ideally, I'd like Get-ChildItem to return immediately after finding the directory and not continue searching the entire tree.

Comment: try `Get-ChildItem -Path c:\ -Recurse -Filter childDirToFind`

Comment: With aliases: `gci x:\start -dir -rec -filter childDirToFind |? {$_.Parent.Name -eq 'parentDir'} | select -first 1`

Comment: BTW, as the search should stop with the first find a trailing `\lev7..` isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where parent is `drivers` and child is `etc`

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Recurse -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { $_.FullName -like '*\drivers\etc' }
```

I added the `-ErrorAction` parameter to hide all the inaccessible folder errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rich Moss and LotPings for steering me in the  right direction.  Both solutions provide the correct results although piping the output to "select -first 1" does have the added benefit of stopping the directory search once the result is found.  I'm not sure why, but using -filter and comparing $*.Parent.Name is twice as fast as comparing $*.FullName (as checked using Measure-Command).  I ultimately went with this:

cgi C:\ -dir -rec -ea SilentlyContinue -filter childDirectory | ? {$_.Parent.Name -eq 'parentDir'} | select -first 1